# Definition of a subcomplex of a $\Delta$-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

I am taking the following as the definition of a $\Delta$-complex.

> (i) one starts with an indexing set $I_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$.
>
> (ii) for each $\alpha \in I_n$, one takes a copy $\sigma_\alpha^n$ of the standard $n$-simplex.
>
> (iii) one forms the disjoint union of all of these simplices, for all $n\geq 0$.
>
> (iv) now require that for each $(n-1)$-dimensional face of $\sigma_\alpha^n$, there is an associated $\sigma_\beta^{n-1}$ for some $\beta \in I_{n-1}$.
>
> (v) now form the quotient space by identifying each $(n-1)$-dimensional face of each $\sigma_\alpha^n$ with $\sigma_\beta^{n-1}$ using the canonical homeomorphism. In particular, these homeomorphisms preserve the ordering of vertices.

The sources I've consulted don't make it clear what a subcomplex is. Can someone give me a rigorous definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that (slightly strange way of phrasing the) definition, a subcomplex should be a sequence $(J_n)_{n\geq0}$ such that

- for each $n\geq0$ we have $J_n\subseteq I_n$, and
- if $\alpha\in J_n$ and $\beta\in I_{n-1}$ are such that $\sigma_b^{n-1}$ is associated to one of the faces of $\sigma_\alpha^n$, then $\beta\in J_{n-1}$.

**N.B.:** you did not tell us where you got that definition from, nor what other sources you consulted. There are *lots* of nice expositions of this subject... With time, I've learned to appreciate C. R. F. Maunder's *Algebraic Topology*, for example.

Comment: The definition is from lectures I took on algebraic topology that don't have typeset notes, so I cannot link you to an electronic version. However, I did reproduce above the lecturer's definition word-for-word. It appears not to be too different from the one in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. What definition would you normally use for $\Delta$-complexes? Thank you for the recommendation; I'll try to find it in my library.

Comment: Incidentally, I've since learned that Eilenberg and Zilber first invented the notion of $\Delta$-complexes under the name "semi-simplicial complexes" in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1969364).